# How use Core Data AddTo... function that is automatically generated

Tags: core-data, swift3, func, nsset, xcode8.2

I have code that gets auto generated when I select "Create NSManagedObject Subclass" from the Editor in the top menu.

There are two functions I'd like to try to use, but I don't seem to be able to access them. The first is `addToListsRel` and the other is `removeFromListsRel`.

Using dot notation, they don't seem to available, so how is it I can use these?

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension Ent_Catalog {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Ent_Catalog> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Ent_Catalog>(entityName: "Ent_Catalog");
    }

    @NSManaged public var brand: String?
    @NSManaged public var id: Int32
    @NSManaged public var image: NSData?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var price: NSDecimalNumber?
    @NSManaged public var qty: NSDecimalNumber?
    @NSManaged public var size: String?
    @NSManaged public var itemsRel: Ent_Items?
    @NSManaged public var listsRel: NSSet?
    @NSManaged public var ingredientsRel: NSSet?
    @NSManaged public var sectionsRel: Ent_Sections?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for listsRel
extension Ent_Catalog {

    @objc(addListsRelObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToListsRel(_ value: Ent_Lists)

    @objc(removeListsRelObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromListsRel(_ value: Ent_Lists)

    @objc(addListsRel:)
    @NSManaged public func addToListsRel(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeListsRel:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromListsRel(_ values: NSSet)

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for ingredientsRel
extension Ent_Catalog {

    @objc(addIngredientsRelObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToIngredientsRel(_ value: Ent_Ingredients)

    @objc(removeIngredientsRelObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromIngredientsRel(_ value: Ent_Ingredients)

    @objc(addIngredientsRel:)
    @NSManaged public func addToIngredientsRel(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeIngredientsRel:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromIngredientsRel(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought the dot notation would look like `Catalog.listsRel.addToListsRel`. Turns out that its actually `Catalog.addToListsRel`

Hope this helps someone else.